# Escaping "<" in Perl-generated XML

Tags: xml, perl

I need to generate an XML output using Perl code.  I'm trying not to use any libraries,  as it's very simple, temporary XML that gets used by another step in the process.

Through my perl code I needed to write something like `"url http://www.123.42 1345&4686=userid:fs/fsfsf"` which resulted in a parser error, and the following XML output:

```
<text>url http://www.123.42 1345&4686=userid:fs/fsfsf  </text>
```

So I attempted to write `"url \<![CDATA[<http://www.123.42 1345&4686=userid:fs/fsfsf]\>"` but that also resulted in a parser error and the following output:

```
<text>URL &lt;![CDATA[http://www.123.42 1345&4686=userid:fs/fsfsf]&gt;</text>
```

I'd like to get this:

```
<text>URL <![CDATA[http://www.123.42 1345&4686=userid:fs/fsfsf]></text>
```

How can I make the XML escape the "<" character?

Comment: Use a library. You'll cost yourself more development time then the savings will be worth.

Comment: It looks like your CDATA brackets are unbalanced.  It should look like: <![CDATA[ http://123.42 ]]>

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure your error doesn't come from the ampersand character `&` ? Try replacing it with `&amp;`

For anything else, please post minimal code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: And moral of the story is ... use a library ;-) (+1)

Comment: the error actualaly comes from the "&" character and that the reason why i was trying to put it inside Cdata section. Is there any other suggested way to display the URL as a text ?

Comment: Exactly as I said in my answer: `&amp;`

Answer (score 1):

```
& is replaced by &#x26;
< is replaced by &#x3c;
> is replaced by &#x3e;
```

Comment: except you may also need to replace " or ' in attributes, and that most of the time you actually don't need to replace >  so maybe using a library would be a good idea

Comment: I agree, but he/she is trying to avoid libraries, and i don't want to judge him/her. :-)  If he/she only needs to scape urls, then replacing & may be enough to avoid parsing errors.

Answer (score 1):

it's not perfect, but it's a start:

```
my $rss = XML::RSS->new();
my @lines = split("\n",$content);
foreach(@lines){
    s/(\S+)<(.*<\/\S+>)$/$1&#x3c;$2/g;
    s/^(<.*>.*)>(.*<\/\S+>)$/$1&#x3e;$2/g;
}
$content = join("\n",@lines);
```

the regex could be better.

Answer (score 0):

Three people have said "use a library" but not one of them has answered the question demonstrating how a library could be used for this problem. That is why everyone hates XML so much, because the libraries are insanely cumbersome and unsuable.

```
sub make_cdata
{
        my $x = shift;
        $x =~ s{]]>}{]]]]><![CDATA[>}g;
        return( "<![CDATA[$x]]>" );
}
```

It is appallingly ugly XML.

I'll give an even better answer, use JSON.